# Entity Framework 6 error with SQL Server 2012 throws EntitySqlException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

I'm developing an intranet app with asp.net mvc 5 with razor syntax and Entity Framework 6, but when I run the app, an `EntitySqlException` occurs.

When I look at the error message, then I have this:

> The entity set or function import 'COVENANTS_RT' is not defined in the entity container 'Model1'.

Here is my Model1 `DbContext`:

```
public partial class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1() : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<covenants> covenants { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<covenants_detalhes> covenants_detalhes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<COVENANTS_RT> COVENANTS_RT { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RT> RT { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<VW_USUARIOS> VW_USUARIOS { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<RT>()
                .Property(e => e.nome_operacao)
                .IsUnicode(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<RT>()
                .HasMany(e => e.COVENANTS_RT)
                .WithRequired(e => e.RT)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.FK_COD_RT);
```

And here is my model class `COVENANTS_RT`:

```
[Table("COVENANTS_RT")]
public partial class COVENANTS_RT
{
        [Key]
        public int CODIGO_COVENANT_PK { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string texto_covenant { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string situacao { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string OBS { get; set; }

        public int FK_COD_RT { get; set; }

        public virtual RT RT { get; set; }
}
```

And the class `RT`:

```
[Table("RT")]
public partial class RT
{
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public RT()
        {
            COVENANTS_RT = new HashSet<COVENANTS_RT>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int PK_CODIGO_RT { get; set; }

        ... 
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<COVENANTS_RT> COVENANTS_RT { get; set; }
}
```

And the code where error occurs in razor page:

```
@model site_covenants.Models.RT 
@{
    Layout = null;
}
...

@foreach (var Item in Model.COVENANTS_RT )
```

So, what I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code here `public partial class Model1 : DbContext` is actually your DbContext and not a model. Is always better to name your objects accordingly.

For example: `public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext` inseatd of `Model1`.

In order to use fluent api you need to override the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<covenants> covenants { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<covenants_detalhes> covenants_detalhes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<COVENANTS_RT> COVENANTS_RT { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RT> RT { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<VW_USUARIOS> VW_USUARIOS { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext() 
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RT>()
            .Property(e => e.nome_operacao)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RT>()
            .HasMany(e => e.COVENANTS_RT)
            .WithRequired(e => e.RT)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.FK_COD_RT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to copy all the class to de question. But I edited that.